# Excel - Selecting a cell with a formula - none of the input cells are marked with colour

Tags: excel-formula, colors

Excel

The input cells are marked with colour upon inserting a formula. But upon selecting formulas, the cells are not dispayed/marked, and this makes the spreadsheet less readable and thereby reduce my workflow.

The problem has been presented here too, but without any proper answer/solution:
https://superuser.com/questions/1228416/cells-referenced-in-formula-not-displaying

[Inserting a formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tidr5.jpg)

[Selecting a cell with a formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0aBH.jpg)

I did as explained by others in the link provided, but they didn't help unfortunately.

PS. I do have macros enabled, and work with them a bit. But nothing that should turn on/off such functions...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I didn't manage to identify what caused the problem, and neither the solution.

I ran my macro a couple of times, and it suddenly worked. I don't even remember if it was at the first run.

Sorry guys, for you others might looking for the same solution as I did...

The macros were only making some formulas and autofill them for specific ranges...